# How to create a live media stream with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-audio-api

I am wanting to create a live audio stream from one device to a node server which can then broadcast that live feed to several front ends.

I have searched extensively for this and have really hit a wall so hoping somebody out there can help.

I am able to get my audio input from the `window.navigator.getUserMedia` API.

```
getAudioInput(){
  const constraints = { 
    video: false, 
    audio: {deviceId: this.state.deviceId ? {exact: this.state.deviceId} : undefined},
  };

  window.navigator.getUserMedia(
    constraints, 
    this.initializeRecorder, 
    this.handleError
  );
}
```

This then passes the stream to the `initializeRecorder` function which utilises the `AudioContext` API to create a createMediaStreamSource`

```
initializeRecorder = (stream) => {
  const audioContext = window.AudioContext;
  const context = new audioContext();
  const audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  const bufferSize = 2048;
  // create a javascript node
  const recorder = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
  // specify the processing function
  recorder.onaudioprocess = this.recorderProcess;
  // connect stream to our recorder
  audioInput.connect(recorder);
  // connect our recorder to the previous destination
  recorder.connect(context.destination);
}
```

In my `recorderProcess` function, I now have an `AudioProcessingEvent` object which I can stream.

Currently I am emitting the audio event as as a stream via a socket connection like so:

```
recorderProcess = (e) => {
  const left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
  this.socket.emit('stream', this.convertFloat32ToInt16(left))
}
```

Is this the best or only way to do this? Is there a better way by using `fs.createReadStream` and then posting the an endpoint via Axios? As far as I can tell this will only work with a file as opposed to a continuous live stream?

**Server**

I have a very simple socket server running ontop of express. Currently I listen for the stream event and then emit that same input back out:

```
io.on('connection', (client) => {

  client.on('stream', (stream) => {
    client.emit('stream', stream)
  });

});
```

Not sure how scalable this is but if you have a better suggestion, I'm very open to it.

**Client**

Now this is where I am really stuck:

On my client I am listening for the `stream` event and want to listen to the stream as audio output in my browser. I have a function that receives the event but am stuck as to how I can use the arrayBuffer object that is being returned.

```
retrieveAudioStream = () => {
  this.socket.on('stream', (buffer) => {
     // ... how can I listen to the buffer as audio
  })
}
```

1. Is the way I am streaming audio the best / only way I can upload to the node server?
2. How can I listen to the arrayBuffer object that is being returned on my client side?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is the way I am streaming audio the best / only way I can upload to the node server?

Not really the best but i have seen worse, its not the only way either using websockets its considered ok from point of view since you want things to be "live" and not keep sending http post request every 5sec.

> 2. How can I listen to the arrayBuffer object that is being returned on my client side?

You can try this [BaseAudioContext.decodeAudioData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData) to listen to data streamed, the example is pretty simple.

---

From the code snippets you provide i assume you want to build something from scratch to learn how things work.

In that case, you can try [MediaStream Recording API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API) along with an websocket server that sends the chunks to X clients so they can reproduce the audio, etc.

It would make sense to invest time into [WebRTC API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API), to learn how to stream from client to another client.

Also take a look at the links below for some useful information.

- [(stackoverflow) Get live streaming audio from NodeJS server to clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456169/get-live-streaming-audio-from-nodejs-server-to-clients)
- [(github) video-conference-webrtc](https://github.com/lucaslouca/video-conference-webrtc)
- [twitch.tv tech stack article](https://blog.twitch.tv/twitch-engineering-an-introduction-and-overview-a23917b71a25)
- [rtc.io](https://github.com/rtc-io/rtc/)

Comment: Are you saying WebRTC would be the better option? I have avoided WebRTC as it is my understanding the client streaming has to upload to every connected user which will cause bandwidth issues for the uploader. We also want to pass through a server so we can keep track of all the uploaders.

I do not necessarily want to build something from scratch. I am happy to use existing libraries but I have struggled to find anything that suits my needs. Have you got any recommendations?

Comment: It sounds like `BaseAudioContext.decodeAudioData` is what I need to be able to listen back to the incoming audio stream. I have tried several times to get this working with my incoming stream of arrayBuffer chunks but keep getting an error around requiring an `audioBuffer` instead. Do you know how I can get `BaseAudioContext.decodeAudioData` to work with my set up or do I need to change how I am uploading my audio stream?

Comment: the example given by MDN https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/decode-audio-data/ is really simple on how to listen, recording  requires Media Recorder API but because of the experimental status you can use libraries like `MediaStreamRecorder` https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder you can capture audio and stream buffers to server, server then just sends the buffer to clients nothing more.